# Serialize custom object to XML

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I'm trying to create a class which I can serialize to produce the following XML:

```
<chart palette='1'>
  <categories>
    <category label='2001' />
    <category label='2002' />
```

..etc

I have a class which look something like this:

```
[XmlRoot("chart")]
public class Chart
{        
    [XmlAttributeAttribute("palette")]
    public string Palette;

    [XmlElement("categories")]
    public List<Category> Categories = new List<Category>();
}

[XmlRoot("category")]
public class Category
{
    [XmlAttributeAttribute("label")]
    public string Label;
}
```

However, this does not produce the desired chart->categories->category@label structure. The XmlRoot on the Category class doesn't seem to be used.
Here is the output I have from that code:

```
 <chart palette="2">
  <categories label="2002" /> 
 </chart>
```

How can I get the XML structure I want?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [XmlArrayAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlarrayattribute.aspx) and [XmlArrayItemAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlarrayitemattribute.aspx)

```
[XmlRoot("chart")]
public class Chart
{        
    [XmlAttributeAttribute("palette")]
    public string Palette;

    [XmlArray("categories")]
    [XmlArrayItem("category")]
    public List<Category> Categories = new List<Category>();
}


public class Category
{
    [XmlAttributeAttribute("label")]
    public string Label;
}
```

Sometimes is can be useful to just create the xml structure you want, and then use xsd.exe to generate classes from it. This has to be done in a 2-step process, first generating an xsd file, and then classes from that.

```
xsd.exe something.xml
xsd.exe something.xsd /classes
```

This will probably not give the exact result you want (unless you have a really good xsd, and don't just generate it from the xml), but does give some ideas

Comment: Thanks, it works! You have basically the same answer as Grzenio, but got the accepted answer because you had extra info.

Answer (score 6):

Should be:

```
[XmlRoot("chart")]
public class Chart
{        
    [XmlAttributeAttribute("palette")]
    public string Palette;

    [XmlArray("categories")]
    [XmlArrayItem("category")]
    public List<Category> Categories = new List<Category>();
}

[XmlRoot("category")]
public class Category
{
    [XmlAttribute("label")]
    public string Label;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar idea and wound up writing a custom base class to handle it. Check out my write up at http://www.ideosity.com/ASP-NET/Object-to-XML-lab.aspx. I think it will get you heading in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Even though this is for ASP.NET, you may find this link useful

[XML Serialization in ASP.NET](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020113423/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/012302-1.shtml)

It tells you how you can work both ways when it comes to serialization.

Also, don’t forget the xsd.exe tool you can use via the **command prompt** which comes with Visual Studio (I used .NET 2005)

For example, you could create the following schema by passing your XML file to it

e.g. **xsd yourfile.xml**

You can then use the xsd generated to create a serialization class, which is basically an object model of the XML with a class for each node by passing the schema to xsd

e.g. **xsd yourfile.xsd /c /l:C**

Again, this is based around .NET so apologies if this is not of interest to the original poster.